# Count the number of Leap Year Days in a temporal difference in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm trying to determine the number of leap year days between two different dates for an app that goes back to the 19thC - here is a method example:

```
-(NSInteger)leapYearDaysWithinEraFromDate:(NSDate *) startingDate toDate:(NSDate *) endingDate {

// this is for testing - it will be changed to a datepicker object
NSDateComponents *startDateComp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[startDateComp setSecond:1];
[startDateComp setMinute:0];
[startDateComp setHour:1];
[startDateComp setDay:14];
[startDateComp setMonth:4];
[startDateComp setYear:2005];

NSCalendar *GregorianCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

//startDate declared in .h//
startDate = [GregorianCal dateFromComponents:startDateComp];
NSLog(@"This program's start date is %@", startDate);


NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *temporalDays = [GregorianCal components:unitFlags fromDate:startDate toDate:today options:0];

NSInteger days = [temporalDays day];

// then i will need code for the number of leap year Days

return 0;//will return the number of 2/29 days

}
```

So I have the number of TOTAL days between the dates. Now I need to subtract the number of leap year days???

PS - I know there are two leap year days in this example but the app will go back to the 19th century...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well, you are overcomplicating this. I think this is what you want:

```
NSUInteger leapYearsInTimeFrame(NSDate *startDate, NSDate *endDate)
{
    // check to see if it's possible for a leap year (e.g. endDate - startDate > 1 year)
    if ([endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate] < 31556926)
        return 0;

    // now we go year by year
    NSUInteger leapYears = 0;
    NSUInteger startYear = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:startDate].year;
    NSUInteger numYears = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:endDate].year - startYear;

    for (NSUInteger currentYear = startYear; currentYear <= (startYear + numYears); currentYear++) {
        if (currentYear % 400 == 0)
            // divisible by 400 is a leap year
            leapYears++;
        else if (currentYear % 100 == 0)
            /* not a leap year, divisible by 100 but not 400 isn't a leap year */ 
            continue;
        else if (currentYear % 4 == 0)
            // divisible by 4, and not by 100 is a leap year
            leapYears++;
        else 
            /* not a leap year, undivisble by 4 */
            continue;
    }

    return leapYears;    
}
```

Comment: This will be off by one if the ending year is a leap year. The test should be currentYear <= (startYear + numYears).

Comment: @RoshDamunki 1900 is NOT a leap year. Check wikipedia, years divisible by 100 but not 400 are not leap years.

Comment: Yes I did see that just after I posted. It appears to be working great now. Thank you thank you

Answer (score 3):

For **Swift**

```
func getLeapCount(startDate : NSDate , endDate : NSDate)-> Int{
    var intialDate = startDate
    var dateComponent = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponent.day = 1
    var leapCount = 0;
    var currentCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        while (intialDate.compare(endDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending) {
            intialDate = currentCalendar.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponent, toDate: intialDate, options: NSCalendarOptions.allZeros)!            
            if self.isLeapYear(startDate){
                ++leapCount
            }
    }

    return leapCount
}
func isLeapYear (year : NSDate )-> Bool{
    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let year = cal.component(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: year)
    return (( year%100 != 0) && (year%4 == 0)) || year%400 == 0;
}
```

Comment: I used the code directly because I am using Swift but the questioner is a Objc programmer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to iterate through all years between the two dates, and call a function increments a counter if it is a leap year. (from Wikipedia)

```
if year modulo 400 is 0 then 
   is_leap_year
else if year modulo 100 is 0 then 
   not_leap_year
else if year modulo 4 is 0 then 
   is_leap_year
else
   not_leap_year
```

That will give you the number of leap years, and thus the number of leap year days you need to subtract.
There may be more efficient methods, but this is the simplest I can think of right now.

Comment: At least you could have given the Objc code example.